# Google Sheets: How to conditionally populate a tab with specific rows from another tab

Tags: google-sheets

I have a [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gGIxfQVac0Bh6v97CGu8D4MuW_w6B_tbqmxyKQwqUco/edit#gid=0) that has information populated on the first tab `completed training`. The other tabs in this sheet represent different departments. I would like to pull data from each row from the `completed training` tab to the tab of the respective department as names are added to the document, based on whether or not the `Completed?` row says `yes`.

For example, if `Jane Doe` from `CS` has completed the training, I would like to have the document automatically populate that row in the `CS` tab in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a filter formula to achieve this:

`=FILTER('Completed Training'!A2:G, 'Completed Training'!C2:C="People", 'Completed Training'!D2:D="Yes")`

Change `"[DEPT NAME]"` to whatever department you want to filter. I have tested this in a copy of your sheet and it works for me. Please let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Hi @kaitlynmm569 as I understand it, it wants it to populate the cells in the same original rows, so ```FILTER``` wouldn't be an option because it removes the blank rows.

Comment: @DigitalFarmer It took me a few times of rereading the original question to understand where you were getting that from, but I see what you are saying, thank you for letting me know. I am still going to leave my answer as is because it may provide an answer the OP didn't realize they wanted, and just gives some variation to yours (multiple answers of the same exact thing aren't always helpful). Thank you though!

Comment: Of course, I commented in case you want to increase the range of the answer with both options like I did.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly for what I wanted. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

1 → To populate on exactly the same line as the original tab!

People tab in A2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(('Completed Training'!C2:C="People")*('Completed Training'!D2:D="Yes"),'Completed Training'!A2:G,""))
```

Sales tab in A2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(('Completed Training'!C2:C="Sales")*('Completed Training'!D2:D="Yes"),'Completed Training'!A2:G,""))
```

CS tab in A2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(('Completed Training'!C2:C="CS")*('Completed Training'!D2:D="Yes"),'Completed Training'!A2:G,""))
```

If you were going to use it in only one line, you could use `AND(condition_1,condition_2)` for multiple conditions, but in `ARRAYFORMULA()` you can't use `AND()`, so to get around this we use `(condition_1)*(condition_2)`, which works exactly the same way.

2 → To always populate the first rows without blank rows between the values!

People tab in A2:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER('Completed Training'!A2:G,'Completed Training'!C2:C="People",'Completed Training'!D2:D="Yes"))
```

Sales tab in A2:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER('Completed Training'!A2:G,'Completed Training'!C2:C="Sales",'Completed Training'!D2:D="Yes"))
```

CS tab in A2:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER('Completed Training'!A2:G,'Completed Training'!C2:C="CS",'Completed Training'!D2:D="Yes"))
```